# How to print out actual object value instead of memory address in gdb?

Tags: c++, c, gdb

```
(gdb) print inputInfo
$8 = (SObjectRecInput *) 0x7fffffffced0
```

For example, when I want to check the value of inputInfo, it prints out:

```
0x7fffffffced0
```

And its type is 'SObjectRecInput'.

How to actually print out its value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inputInfo` appears to have a pointer type, so dereference it:

```
(gdb) print *inputInfo
```

Comment: Yes, it worked! What about reference? It automatically prints out values?

Comment: @marlon the `print` command will print whatever you give it depending on its type.  So if you give it a pointer type it prints the pointer value.